# Angular2 Routing gives 404 when reloading page

Tags: angular, dart

I've written my first Angular Dart app, but something is wrong wit the routing ...

```
@Component(
    selector: 'ahpmui',
    template: '''
        <strong>My First Angular 2 App - {{name}}</strong>
        <br />
        <router-outlet>
        </router-outlet>
        <br />
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['HomePage']">Home</a> |
            <a [routerLink]="['DashboardPage']">Dashboard</a>
        </nav>
    ''',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: const [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HomePage,
        DashboardPage
    ]

)
@RouteConfig(const [
    const Route(path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardPage, name: 'DashboardPage', useAsDefault: true),
    const Route(path: '/home', component: HomePage, name: 'HomePage')
])
class AppComponent {

    String name = "Sample App";

}
```

HomePage:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'home-page',
    template: '<strong>This is the Home Page</strong>')
class HomePage {}
```

DashboardPage:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'dashboard-page',
    template: '<strong>This is the Dashboard Page</strong>')
class DashboardPage {}
```

main.dart:

```
// bootstrap angular2
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'),
        provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
    ]);
```

When my app starts up, it goes to `http://localhost:8080/dashboard` as expected, when clicking on the `Home` link, it correctly goes to `http://localhost:8080/home`. If I now refresh the page, I get an error `404`

[image]

I then change the bootstrap part to this:

```
 // bootstrap angular2
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/#/'),
        provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
    ]);
```

URLs are now as follow (I prefer it in this style since the legacy app is using this same url format)

```
http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard
http://localhost:8080/#/home
```

If I hit refresh, no longer get the error 404, but the page redirects back to the `http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard` page.

I'm running the app using `pub serve`

Is there any way I can tie in the `onHashChange` event into the Angular Router so that if I refresh `http://localhost:8080/#/home` that it actually routes to the HomeComponent ?

Comment: AFAIR the URL format is like this with `HashLocationStrategy` anyway. What happens when you remove the `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, ...)` line entirely (not sure if it's required for `HashLocationStrategy`). Can you please also try `<base href="/">` (instead of `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, ...)`)as first element in the head tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS,` from `AppComponent`, you have them in `bootstrap()` already. `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should be provided only once.

Comment: Changing the AppBaseHref to just `/` with the HashProvider also gives me the desired `/#/home` URL format :-D

Comment: Yup, as expected :D