# Angular2 Dart with pub serve localhost refresh page 404

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

In angular2 dart the hashbang is removed from routing by default which makes for nice urls. However, when I run the app with pub serve, I can't refresh any page other than the root or I get a 404 that says for example "Could not find asset web/dashboard in package angular2_quickstart."

I know there's got to be a simple solution.

Is there a way to force pub serve to capture all routes at the host and always serve index.html like single page apps do? Or what is the developer workflow for developing and serving your application locally?

This question is similar, but I'd prefer not to use the hashbang: [Angular2 Routing gives 404 when reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616385/angular2-routing-gives-404-when-reloading-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pub serve` doesn't support `PathLocationStrategy`

Either you use some proxy that adds support for `PathLocationStrategy` or you configure Angular2 to use `HashLocationStrategy`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, const Provider(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Looks like it is also is important to add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` here or it doesn't work.  And there should be a '[' before the 'const' above.

Comment: You are right, but I assumed that you did. Without the router you wouldn't get the 404.

Comment: Here is also a link to an issue that exists in pub's github  https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1374

Comment: I had the `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in my app_component.dart instead of the main.dart. I moved it and its fine. Again, thanks for your help